# Different versions of UNIX sort handle case differently

Tags: unix, shell, sorting

I am using `sort` both on Mac OS X and Ubuntu Linux, and I am observing a different handling of uppercase/lowercase comparisons.

On Mac OS X, `sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93` gives the behavior I expect:

```
$ sort <<EOF
> Aa
> aa
> Ab
> ab
> EOF
Aa
Ab
aa
ab
```

On Ubuntu, `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.5` seems to ignore case:

```
$ sort <<EOF
> Aa
> aa
> Ab
> ab
> EOF
aa
Aa
ab
Ab
```

Is there a way to disable this behavior? I need case-sensitive sort.
I tried to change the `LOCALE` to `C` and nothing changed.

Alternatively, is there any other simple utility that sorts large files treating each line just as a byte string?

Comment: Interesting. I suppose it takes 5 lines to write the `sort` you want in Perl or Python, so perhaps someone can contribute that as an answer, if such a solution is acceptable to you.

Comment: UNIX `sort` does external sort, I need to sort files that do not fit in RAM. I don't think you can do that in 5 lines of Perl :)

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant by "large". Good to make it clear then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using POSIX:  'export LANG=POSIX'

Comment: you're welcome ;) setting LANG to POSIX means the characters are
ASCII encoded..in some linux distros root user has LANG set to POSIX, normal users use <lang>.UTF-8, therefore sorting is different.